# What's wrong with this code? (Converting char* to string)

Tags: c++, string, char

I'm trying to learn C++, and I learn by doing...

What this code's end-result is going to be is that it outputs the `char* argv[2]` to a function which only takes strings as input, and it will output a changed string.

How can I convert `char* argv[2]` into a string?

Everything I've tried ends up crashing my command prompt, for some reason.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::string com2 = argv[2];
    char* com1[4];
    com1[1] = "-f";
    com1[2] = "--file";
    com1[3] = "-t";
    com1[4] = "--text";
    if (strcmp(argv[1], com1[1]) == 0) {

        cout << com2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Array indexs run from `0` to `N - 1`, where `N` is the number of elements in the array. Therefore `4` is an invalid index, and results in undefined behaviour.

Ensure the correct number of arguments have been supplied to the program, by checking the value of `argc`, before accessing elements in `argv`.

Comment: @AcronymTheRapper - If hmjd wrote the correct answer, please mark his answer as the "right one".

Comment: It said I had to wait 2 minutes before I can do that. I may be new to SackOverflow, but I'm not THAT stupid. lol

Answer (score 1):

`com1[4]` is invalid, and results in undefined behavior. Arrays in C and C++ are 0-based, so valid indexes for your array would be `0,1,2,3`.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables in C and C++ are virtually always automatic (unless declared `static`), which means that they are placed on the stack. The stack grows downwards, while arrays grow upwards in memory. The combination of these two means that usually there is something important after the last element of any stack array and writing past it is very dangerous (it is always dangerous but in the case of stack arrays it is exceptionally dangerous). Assigning to `com1[4]` writes past the end of the `com1` array, possibly overwriting some data member(s) of the `std::string` instance `com2` or destroying the stack frame of the `main` function (depends on how the compiler puts `com1` and `com2` in the stack).

If you start the program with one argument only then `argv` would have only 2 elements and `argv[2]` would:

- lead to access past the end of the argument list, and
- give a random value, which in most cases would not point to character data at all.

If you start the program without any arguments, then `argv` would have only 1 element and both `argv[1]` and `argv[2]` would be out-of-bounds access and would return random values. To prevent these cases, you should put the following at the very beginning of your program:

```
if (argc < 3) {
   cerr << "ERROR: Provide at least 2 arguments" << endl;
   return 1;
}
```

Note that `argv` always has at least one element (i.e. `argv[0]` is always a correct reference) - the name of the executable file. Hence `argc` is always greater of equal to `1`.